# Утечка памяти Андройд. (HttpURLConnection)

Tags: android, android-fragment

Моё приложение получает данные сервера(иногда большие данные).При переходе в

```
Activity->FragmentStatePagerAdapter
```

приложение за раз отправляет около 5 запросов на сервер в разных потоках (использую AsyncTask).

Когда приходят большие данные, лог пишет.

```
E/: [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0008]
 I/eltasecurity.s: Background concurrent copying GC freed 48(39KB) 
 AllocSpace objects, 17(22MB) LOS objects, 50% free, 11MB/23MB, paused 
 5.327ms total 56.798ms
```

И ни каких ошибок больше нет.
Вот метод через который я отправляю запросы.

```
    public static String getResponseFromURL(URL url) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        String str = "mobile=123";
        os.write(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        urlConnection.connect();
        try {
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
            scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");
            boolean hasInput = scanner.hasNext();
            if (hasInput) {
                return scanner.next();
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Если я что-то делаю не так, просьба укажите.

Comment: покажите как и где вы запускаете `AsyncTask`

Comment: Если оно работает, не тормозит и не падает - то можно и не обращать внимание на это. Ели же не работает что-то, то можно, например, не использовать мало кем используемые ныне AsyncTask и HttpURLConnection и тем более не использовать AsyncTask не по назначению - для больших задач он не предназначен. Если вам надо что-то тяжёлое качать - запускайте сервис, в нём отдельный поток, качайте данные и отправляйте в нужное место. Но тут, чтобы было красиво и удобно хорошо бы и кучу либ и паттернов использовать. Retrofit/OkHttp, RxJava, DI